# Got fired before second interview

Tags: termination

Suppose a person gets fired from his current job. He is in the second round of interviews with another company. How does he tell the company about his termination from his former company?

Comment: Why would one wish to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal: If they ask are you currently employed at your company what would one say? If they don't bring it up, one shouldn't disclose anything?

Comment: If they ask be truthful. But if they do not bring it up why should you?

Comment: @EdHeal: Former companies cannot tell other companies that a person was fired, correct? They can only verify the dates the employee worked there?

Comment: Of course they can tell other companies that you was fired. But most companies do not. Most references is that the person worked from X to Y. It is not in there interest to do so - possibility of litigation and all that hassle.

Comment: Is this really "fired"  for cause or just being made redundant

Answer (score 6):

Although I must admit that I was never in such a situation before. I would have to advocate "Do not say anything" unless they ask. When they do, be truthful and frank about the nature of your separation. If at fault, portray it as a lesson that you have learned and will not commit again. If not, explain as succinct as possible what happened. Something to think about is if you asked any of your former coworkers as references.

Comment: I agree. The general rule when in doubt at an interview, is not to bring up anything if you don't think it will reflect positively on you. Unless of course you are asked about it. Such as "what is your current status". Don't lie!